# How to create a temporary UInputDevice in linux from scratch?

Tags: rust, evdev

I am aware that I can use

```
let f = File::open("/dev/input/event0").unwrap();
let dummy = evdev_rs::UInputDevice::create_from_device(&Device::new_from_fd(f).unwrap()).unwrap();
```

But how would I create a dummy device that would be able to do all events(keyboard, mouse, etc) from no previous model? Also, I do not completely understand evdev, but if I were to receive an event from my keyboard and then write that exact event to the dummy would it work?

Edit: Sorry for the ambiguity, I realized that I actually want to create a UInputDevice able to produce events.

Comment: To clarify your question, do you want to
1. create an instance of `UInputDevice` that can produce fake events that appear as if they came from a real evdev device?
2. create an evdev device on an operating system level — in which case this question the "rust" part is perhaps not relevant to the question?
3. something else?

Comment: Look at my question, maybe it will help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060804/virtual-keyboard-linux-libevdev-sending-event